# How do I ask nmap to probe designated service type, and do not run scripts?

Tags: nmap

I would like to probe if a port is running socks or squid service, but nmap runs all service probes by default, can I change that?

Also from the debug output, there's a NSE script pre-scanning, can I disable that too?

P.S attached nmap command

```
nmap 58.250.87.87 -p 10080 -sV -A --version-intensity 8 -Pn -n -T4 --max-retries 0 -vvv --debug
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is to remove `-A` from your command, since that implicitly requests scripts in the "default" category (being the equivalent of `-sV -sC -O --traceroute`.

Next, you will still have scripts in the "version" category running. These are specifically designed to enhance the `-sV` version scan by probing services that will not respond adequately to a single static probe. If you really need to turn these off, you can (since Nmap 6.49BETA1) set the `script-intensity` script argument to 0: `--script-args script-intensity=0`. This will prevent version-category scripts from running unless you select them by name.

Comment: `-sV` works for me

Comment: @bonsaiviking How about disable port-scanning only do version-detection? I prefer `-sV` without port-scanning first.

Comment: @RyanChou Nmap doesn't work that way; the version detection engine only knows about the ports that port scan detected as open. However, you can limit your scan to only the ports you want to probe with the `-p` option. For instance, if you only want to fingerprint the HTTP server, use `-p 80`

Comment: @bonsaiviking I knew that nmap doesn't work as I said. I have done more research on nmap manual and found nothing could limit nmap just do version-detecion phase only, while I prefer to do zmap port-scanning first and combine the port-open hosts to do version-detection with nmap. So it doesn't need to do port-scanning again. Is there any solution or improvements on it?

Comment: @bonsaiviking Could version-detecion (-sV) provide an advance options to specify amount of Probes? like `--probes GetRequest,SSLSessionReq` it send the probes only by `--probes <probes>`.

Comment: @RyanChou The "port scanning" in this case is simply a check that the port is open. For each given port, you are guaranteed to spend at least 10x as much time in the version detection scan as in the port scan phase. There is no performance gain to be had here. You can limit the probes by using `--version-intensity` or using a modified copy of the `nmap-service-probes` file with the `--versiondb` option

Comment: @bonsaiviking How about run the nmap instances in parallel for speed up the version-detection phase? I am willing to run multiple nmap instances in distributed nodes or multi process which may accelerate the whole version-detection phase. How much performance we could gain.?

Comment: @bonsaiviking I noticed that the probes has been sent one by one in nmap process according to `--version-trace`. It is impossible to speed up the phase by adjust the nmap options. so i thought that there is only one way to complete the large network scan by distributing nmap scan nodes.

Comment: @RyanChou Multiple target services are already scanned in parallel, but each single service gets probes sent sequentially because the engine keeps state about which probes have received which replies (e.g. an early probe may receive a reply that identifies FTP, but further probing is required to determine the ftpd version). You can't send probes in a different order and expect the same result.

Comment: @bonsaiviking OK, I got it. and how about providing an option `--probes` GetRequest,SSLSessionReq` so that we could scan the ports by probes we specified. If I added new probe such as FooRequest into nmap-service-probes. I could probably scan a bunch of ports by the probe. I have no idea how to do it on nmap.

Answer (score -1):

From nmap help:

> -sV: Probe open ports to determine service/version info
>   --version-intensity : Set from 0 (light) to 9 (try all probes)
>   --version-light: Limit to most likely probes (intensity 2)
>   --version-all: Try every single probe (intensity 9)
>   --version-trace: Show detailed version scan activity (for debugging)

From my understanding, you don't have the option to select which probes you want to execute. If I'm right, then the only option would be compiling nmap.

If you download the code, there is a file called: `nmap-service-probes`, which contains a list of regexp which are used to identify the services. I don't know how nmap uses this file, but I guess that if you remove any other than the ones you want, it will only search for those probes.

As of disabling "pre-scanning", take a look to the `--disable-FEATURE` argument of `configure` (in case you go on the way of compiling nmap). Not sure if that is useful but it may take you in some direction.

My recommendation is to wait and see if someone knows a way to achieve it without compiling it. If not, you have this option.